# Rearranging one list based on the other in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `second_lines_different_folders` and `different_lines_folders`. I want to rearrange different_lines_folders according to rearranged_list. Both the lists have one to one correspondence. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_lines_different_folders = [404, 403, 405, 404, 405]
different_lines_folders = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

# Create a dictionary to store grouped values
grouped_dict = defaultdict(list)

# Iterate over the elements of the list and group them
for value in second_lines_different_folders:
    grouped_dict[value].append(value)

# Convert the dictionary values to a list of sublists
rearranged_list = [v for k, v in sorted(grouped_dict.items())]

print(f"Rearranged list: {rearranged_list}")
```

The expected output is

```
Rearranged list: [[403], [404, 404], [405, 405]]
Rearranged folders: [[5],[4,7],[6,9]]
```

The current output is

```
Rearranged list: [[403], [404, 404], [405, 405]]
```

Comment: you can `zip` the values together, sort according to the first item of the tuple, then extract the second item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) the two lists and use the 4xx number as a key for two dictionaries, optionally sort the key in a final step:

```
second_lines_different_folders = [404, 403, 405, 404, 405]
different_lines_folders = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

out1 = {}
out2 = {}

for a,b in zip(second_lines_different_folders,
               different_lines_folders):
    out1.setdefault(a, []).append(a)
    out2.setdefault(a, []).append(b)

# for sorted output
order = sorted(out1)
out1 = [out1[k] for k in order]
out2 = [out2[k] for k in order]
```

Output:

```
# out1
[[403], [404, 404], [405, 405]]

# out2
[[5], [4, 7], [6, 9]]
```

---

*NB. using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) instead of `defaultdict` but this is just a detail, both are possible.*

Variant with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

second_lines_different_folders = [404, 403, 405, 404, 405]
different_lines_folders = [4, 5, 6, 7, 9]

out1 = defaultdict(list)
out2 = defaultdict(list)

for a,b in zip(second_lines_different_folders,
               different_lines_folders):
    out1[a].append(a)
    out2[a].append(b)

# for sorted output
order = sorted(out1)
out1 = [out1[k] for k in order]
out2 = [out2[k] for k in order]
out1, out2
```